# FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have Views field from one of my tables in the database. At first i allowed it to take nulls, and now it disallowed it to take null. The problem is that that exception is being thrown when i convert the SqlReader instance to an int..here is the code:

```
       try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        if (dr != null && dr.Read() && dr["Views"] != null && dr["PageNumber"] != null && dr["Replies"]!=null)
        {
            Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            ThreadName = dr["ThreadTitle"].ToString();
            Views = int.Parse(dr["Views"].ToString());//it is being thrown here when i try to convert it to an int..How can i prevent that mistake from being thrown?
            Replies = int.Parse(dr["Replies"].ToString());
            Topic = dr["Theme"].ToString();
            Subtopic = dr["Topics"].ToString();
            PageNumber = int.Parse(dr["PageNumber"].ToString());
            Time = (DateTime)dr["Time"];
        }
        dr.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe there are null values present, Did you check the value of *dr["Views"].ToString()*

Comment: If u read my question, you would notice that i said i did allow nulls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid exception while convertion, use Int32.TryParse always.

Comment: I think that it worked: Views = (Int32.TryParse(dr["Views"].ToString(), out result3))?int.Parse(dr["Views"].ToString()):0;

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 View = dr["Views"] as int? ?? 0;
```

If the value in the db is null then above it's being cast into a nullable int which can accept nulls.

Use the coalesce operator ?? to set the value of View to some other value (in this case 0) if the value in the database IS null.

Comment: i got an invalid cast exception ::

Comment: What is the field datatype in the database - was assuming null was your problem, but maybe something else??

Comment: It is int ... may be is should delete the whole database and start from the begining. How do i do that?

Comment: Sorry - I'm bad - forgot the issue with DbNulls - modified above - using "as" to cast should be ok.

Comment: How do i convert datetime type  in the database to DateTime object  Time = (DateTime)dr["Time"];

Comment: the same will work: object Time = dr["Time"] as DateTime? ?? DateTime.MinValue;

Comment: Why do i need the MinValue property?

Comment: I get indexOutofRangeException. Why is that :(

Comment: OK - Ignore me here - haven't tried this one myself but DateTime? is quite different to DateTime so my suggestion won't work. See here instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192121/how-do-i-use-datetime-tryparse-with-a-nullabledatetime - Note that with any BASIC value type though, e.g. int, bool, long, decimal, this type of code will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [int.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) to avoid the error. If the probem is just the null, I would recommend to use [System.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) to handle these situations, because it's safer and clear:

```
View = System.Convert.ToInt32(dr["Views"]);
```

Comment: I sent the link to the doc. Anyway try with: View = System.Convert.ToInt32(dr["Views"]);

Comment: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. - Invalid Cast Exception

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if(dr["Views"] != DBNull)
{
// do your parse here
}
```