# Trying to parse String to Datetime in property (C#)

Tags: c#, datetime, properties

Im trying to parse a string a DateTime object. No problem there :-)
My problem comes, when i try to do it directly in a property set method.

I thought i could do this:

```
        private DateTime _fromDate;
        public DateTime FromDate
        {
            get { return _fromDate; }
            set { _fromDate = DateTime.Parse(value); }
        }
```

But I get this error:

"Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'string'"

Does anyone know how to do this, if it can be done at all?

Comment: Do you have an example of "value"?

Comment: value is of type `DateTime` not type `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Use

```
private DateTime _fromDate;
public DateTime FromDate
    {
        get { return _fromDate; }
        set { _fromDate = value; }
    }
```

`value` will be of `DateTime` as the property is of `DateTime`. When someone will assign this property a `DateTime object` it will go in `value`. In Set that value will be assigned to `_fromDate`

Comment: I was trying to build the string to DateTime parser into the property.
But ended up using XmlConvert.ToDateTime to preform the parsing.

Answer (score 3):

`_fromDate` is of type `DateTime`.

`DateTime.Parse` takes a `string` and returns a `DateTime`.

You are passing in `value` *which is already* a `DateTime` and there is no implicit conversion of `DateTime` to `string`.

If you want to directly parse a `string` into a `DateTime` then you'll need a new property which is a `string` type:

```
private DateTime _fromDate;
public string FromDate
{
    get { return _fromDate.ToString(); }
    set { _fromDate = DateTime.Parse(value); }
}
```

Though you would need to a) have some control over the formatting of the string and b) some safety checks on the input string to make sure it didn't just raise an exception if it wasn't a valid date.

Answer (score 2):

The property is of type `DateTime`; you simply cannot pass a string as a value, even if you intend to convert it to a `DateTime` yourself.

In more technical terms, this property results in your class having a method

```
public DateTime get_FromDate(DateTime value)
{
    // your property setter code here
}
```

The method takes a `DateTime` parameter, and there is no way to change that.

If you want to provide a convenient way to convert a string to a `DateTime` to the class's users (perhaps one that uses non-trivial processing) you can expose the conversion as a method on your class. The users would have to explicitly call it every time, but that's life.

Answer (score 2):

You already get the parameter as a `DateTime`, so there's no need for parsing it.

If you really insist that you want to parse it, convert it to a string

```
set { _fromDate = DateTime.Parse(value.ToString()); }
```

But if you do this, you get a datetime, convert it to a string, and convert it back to a datetime, which is... well, not brilliant :)

Answer (score 1):

Not to beat a 4-year dead horse, but I stumbled upon this thread with similar thought process to the OP and wanted to summarize my personal findings with this topic.  Ultimately, if you want to set a DateTime property of an existing object, you must parse it in advance (as previous answers suggest).  However, I was actually concerned with initializing the object and you **CAN** pass a text value to be parsed in the constructor.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(String date)
    {
        DateTime tmpDate;
        DateTime.TryParse(date, out tmpDate);
        if (tmpDate != DateTime.Minvalue)
        {
            FromDate = tmpDate;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentError(("Unable to parse the input string " + date));
        }
```

In my particular case I wanted my DateTime properties to be nullable, so I had to create a method ([pulled from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192121/how-do-i-use-datetime-tryparse-with-a-nullabledatetime)) to handle the parsing (this would be used to parse data externally as well as in the constructor.  e.g.:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(String date)
    {
        DateTime? tmpDate = this.TryParse(date);
        if (tmpDate.hasValue)
        {
            FromDate = tmpDate;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentError(("Unable to parse the input string " + date));
        }
    }
    public DateTime? FromDate { get; set;}

    public DateTime? TryParse(string text)
    {
        DateTime date;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(text, out date))
        {
            return date;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Obviously you would want to create additional constructors and probably have a matching type constructor as your default.

Answer (score 0):

You get the compiler error because `DateTime.Parse(string s)` takes a `string` input parameter, but `value` is of type `DateTime`, which cannot be implicitly converted to `string`.

You don't need to parse the value because it is already `DateTime`, so you can change your code to be `set { _fromDate = value; }`