# Convert String to Nullable DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use DateTime.TryParse with a Nullable<DateTime>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192121/how-do-i-use-datetime-tryparse-with-a-nullabledatetime)

I have this line of code

```
DateTime? dt = Condition == true ? (DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(stringDate) : null;
```

Is this the correct way to convert string to Nullable DateTime, or is there a direct method to convert without *converting* it to DateTime and again *casting* it to Nullable DateTime?

Comment: You may cast null to nullable DateTime: `Condition == true ? Convert.ToDateTime(stringDate) : (DateTime?) null;` :)

Comment: `DateTime? dt = dt.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now);`

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
 DateTime? dt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(date) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(date);
```

Comment: I might suggest `string.IsNullOrEmpty(date)` rather than `date == null`.

Comment: That wouldn't work if a string that was neither empty nor a valid date was passed. For better solutions see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192121/how-do-i-use-datetime-tryparse-with-a-nullabledatetime

Answer (score 16):

You are able to build a method to do this:

```
public static DateTime? TryParse(string stringDate)
{
    DateTime date;
    return DateTime.TryParse(stringDate, out date) ? date : (DateTime?)null;
}
```

Comment: This won't work since date is not a nullable datetime.

Comment: @bret: Did you try this?

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime? dt = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringData) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(dateString));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply assigned without cast at all :)

```
DateTime? dt = Condition == true ? Convert.ToDateTime(stringDate) : null;
```